# Automatically populating payload for REST api post calls

Tags: python, rest, automation

I am trying to build a framework around REST apis where I want to build rest calls ( especially posts ) with payloads automatically being generated as I don't want to make my test scripts look ugly with payloads in them.
The good news is that there is a swagger.yaml file which lists out all the rest endpoints and what they accept for parameters and what they throw out for responses.

I am trying to understand how to use all the tools that I have at my disposal to make the payload generation as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/) to generate fake data to populate your request payload. It also provides an api to get random data anytime.